# How to call a template helper from within the same file?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I have the following helper function:

```
Template.modal.helpers({ 
  permalink: function() {
    var this_id = Session.get("pageId");
    var thisItem = Items.findOne({_id: this_id});
    // console.log("set page id to " + this._id)
    return thisItem['permalink'];
  }
});
```

I want to call this within the same file, I tried

```
permalink();
this.permalink();
```

It didn't work so how do I use this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manage to call a helper "manually", it won't be easy or pretty. What you want to do is declare a regular function which can be used by both the helper and your other code, e.g.:

```
function myPermalinkFunction() {
  var this_id = Session.get("pageId");
  var thisItem = Items.findOne({_id: this_id});
  // console.log("set page id to " + this._id)
  return thisItem['permalink'];
}

Template.modal.helpers({
  permalink: myPermalinkFunction
});

/* elsewhere, within the same file */
  ... myPermalinkFunction() ...
```

In Meteor, anything declared "globally" with `var` or `function` is in fact only visible within its file, so you don't need to worry about polluting the global namespace. If you need to provide a particular context to the "helper" function, you can do so by using `call` or `apply` instead of regular invocation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to call the function. If it's somewhere else (another scope out of closure) in the same file, then define it beforehand:

```
function permalinkHelper() {/* ... */ }
```

If you need to access it within itself, name the function and use this name:

```
Template.modal.helpers({
  permalink : function permalinkHelper() {
    permalinkHelper();
  }
});
```

The second case is recursive calling, and needs a stop condition. As it is written right there it will end up in an InternalError : too much recursion thingy.